# How do I exclude a certain resource update from a chef run?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

What is the easiest way to ignore a certain resource from the command-line?

I am using `chef-solo`

Some users of our product would like to leave a certain file or template unchanged by a chef-run for testing-purposes, and I was hoping for a flexible way to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **action** for template,

```
action :create_if_missing
```

This way, template will be created only if file is not existing.

If you want to specify more complex statement, use *only_if*

```
only_if { node[:some_value] }
```

You can make attributes like

```
default['template']['exclude_FILENAME'] = true
```

and then use it in Chef code. This way you could have file *excludes.rb* in *attributes* directory and change these options if you want.

Simple example:

```
template 'Some template you want to decide if it should be excluded' do
    path       '/tmp/somefile' 
    source     'template.erb'
    only_if     { node['template']['exclude_FILENAME'] }
end
```

This is not ignoring from command line, but you can give them excludes.rb file to edit... Or write simple shell script that asks user if it want to exclude resource and stores info in this file.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

One way you may be able to implement this is with an overlay/union file system (e.g. OverlayFS, AUFS). Overlay filesystem merges the view from multiple folders into one. You would run chef as normal on the base folder, then add an overlay that keeps the files you want as a static file. You can then do tests on top of this. If you want to write over these files, add another layer of writable overlay on top of this, so it catches the writes. To reset, destroy the writable layer; to modify the base image, unapply the layers, rerun chef to modify the base image, and reapply the overlay.

This is in no way using anything chef specific.